# apt only half-sees a package

Tags: linux, debian, package-management

On debian stable, with almost standard sources.list file, I can't install the following package.

```
 $ apt-cache showpkg ttf-mscorefonts-installer
 Package: ttf-mscorefonts-installer
 Versions: 
 ...

 $ apt-cache search ttf-mscorefonts-installer
 (nothing)

 $ apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
 E: Package 'ttf-mscorefonts-installer' has no installation candidate
```

It is clearly available for all platforms: https://packages.debian.org/jessie/ttf-mscorefonts-installer

Could anyone help? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that the package is not in the main section of the repository. It is in the contrib section, which is not enabled by default. So sources.list has to be edited like so:

> deb http://debian.man.ac.uk/debian/ stable main **contrib** non-free

Comment: make sure the bold face word in snoopys answer IS in your sources.list

Comment: Thank you, I just installed Debian 8.1 and had this issue.